# Lingohub - removing unused translation keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to remove unused keys on Lingohub?

I'm just deleting a bunch of unused keys in the translation yml file.
Is there any good and safe way to do this?

edit:

Answer from Lingohub team:

> Hi xyz,
>
> LingoHub will automatically deactivate keys when they are removed from
> a file. So for example you had a file with the following keys:
>
> A B C
>
> And you then upload the same file with the keys
>
> A C
>
> The B key would be deactivated and not shown in the editor or exported
> anymore.
>
> Please note, this behavior is changeable through project settings. So
> make sure you check them before.
>
> Hope that helps.
>
> Best,

This is a partial answer that I wanted. Can I somehow reverse these keys if the mistake is created?
or create more environments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Helmut from LingoHub. I would like to add some additional information on how we handle text segments. As described each text segment is associated with a key. So basically if a File A is uploaded with the keys:

```
a = Home
b = Members
c = Settings
```

LingoHub would create these 3 text segments with the associated key. If the same File is then uploaded with a different set of keys, changes will be applied accordingly. E.g.

```
a = Welcome
c = Settings
d = Logout
```

This would result in following changes:

a would be updated from Home to Welcome
b would be deactivated (note, not deleted)
d would be created.

As mentioned **b** would be deactivated, meaning it doesn't appear in the editor anymore, nor would it be exported in the files. However, if you later add the **b** key again, the text segment would be reactivated. A common use case for this is when you have multiple files and the key is removed from one file and added to another file. In this case you won't lose any history, translations, etc.

Last note, the process I described is the 'default' way, many things can be changed through the settings, so you can tailor the process to your needs.